# Evaluate $\int_0^1 \sqrt{2x-1} - \sqrt{x}$ $dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to calculate the area between the curves $y = \sqrt{x}$ and $y= \sqrt{2x-1}$

Here's the graph: [image]

I've already tried calculating the area with respect to $y$, i.e.

$\int_0^1 (\frac{y^2+1}{2} - y^2)$ $ dx$ 
 
[since $y^2=x$ for the first curve and $\frac{y^2+1}{2}=x$ for the second curve]

And the result for that integral is $1/3$ which should be the same for the result of the integral in question
$\int_0^1 (\sqrt{2x-1} - \sqrt{x})$ $dx$

But, $\int_0^1 (\sqrt{2x-1} - \sqrt{x})$ $dx$ = $\int_0^1 (2x-1)^{1/2}$ $dx$ - $\int_0^1 {x}^{1/2} $ $dx$ 
[let $2x-1 = u$ and $2 dx = du$]
$\Rightarrow$ $\frac 12 \int_0^1 (u)^{1/2}$ $du$ - $\frac{2x^{3/2}}{3}$
$=\frac{u^{3/2}}{3}$ - $\frac{2x^{3/2}}{3}$
$=\frac{(2x-1)^{3/2}}{3}$ - $\frac{2x^{3/2}}{3}$

Evaluated at $x=1$ and $x=0$ and subtracting:
$(\frac{-1}{3})-(\frac{-1}{3})$

Why?

Comment: You can't integrate $\sqrt{2x -1}$ from $0$ to $1$ - the function is only defined for $x \ge \frac12$

Comment: Decompose the area in two regions: $[0,1/2]$ and $[1/2,1].$

Comment: Does it mean I have to evaluate at x=1 and at x= 1/2 and subtract the latter from the former?<br><br> Or could I evaluate at x=0(ignoring the term $\sqrt{2x-1}$ as undefined) and subtract the value at x=0 from the value at x=1?

Answer (score 4):

As noted in the comments the correct way is

$$
    A 
      = \int_0^{1/2} \color{blue}{\sqrt{x}} \, \mathrm{d}x + 
        \int_{1/2}^1 \color{red}{\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{2x-1}} \,\mathrm{d}x 
      = \int_0^1 \frac{y^2+1}{2} - y^2 \mathrm{d}y
      = 1/3
$$

Since $\sqrt{2x-1}$ is not defined for $x<1/2$. Note that you could also have done the integral as

$$
A = \int_0^1 \sqrt{x} \,\mathrm{d}x - \int_{1/2}^1 \sqrt{2x-1} \,\mathrm{d}x
$$

(why?) without it making the computation any easier.

[image]

Comment: But the top curve is $y=\sqrt{x}$ and the bottom curve is $y=\sqrt{2x-1}$. How can they be flipped?

Comment: @Minu: the computation looks correct, the diagram has them switched by mistake.

Comment: I still don't understand how it (the width) can be  $\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{2x-1}$ instead of $ \sqrt{2x-1} - \sqrt{x}$. Could you please explain?

Comment: "without it making the computation any easier" Actually it does since the change of variable $z=2x-1$ shows the second integral is half the first one, and, since a primitive of $\sqrt{x}$ is $\frac23x\sqrt{x}$, one is done.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you can integrate as you have suggested, however, despite the variable y:

$\int_0^1 (\frac{y^2+1}{2} - y^2)\color{red}{dy}=\frac{1}{2}[y-\frac{y^3}{3}]_0^1=\frac{1}{3}$

There is no reason to go back to the variable x.

Comment: hmmm...since when is the integral of $\frac{y^2 + 2}{2} = y?$ Methinks you differentiated that portion of the integral.

Comment: The final integral of $ (\frac{y^2+1}{2} - y^2)dy = \frac 12 (y -\frac{y^3}{3})$. So it is correct.